# Can't add iOS sandbox test credit cards

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-sandbox

I'm trying to test payments on an iOS app.
I have a sandbox account and its worked previously.
When I try and add a test credit card I get the error
"Your Issuer Does Not Yet Offer Support For This Card"
I'm using the cards here [https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing/"](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing/%22)

What I have tried:

- Checking my Region is the UK
- Checking the card details
- Tried several cards
- Tried signing out of my iCloud completely

I'm testing on an iPhone 12 mini using iOS 16.5.1